# port forwarding - Transmission torrent client

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port, bittorrent, editing

I have a problem related to Transmission torrent client. Specifically on a Fedora 23 Linux distribution.

My goal is to increase download speed and surfing on the internet. I found out the best way to do it was port forwarding.

I followed online guides and tried to do it manually via the router page, accessed through the IP address. Then I did the same using the firewall GUI app you can download through the software manager. However, doing the test from preferences in Transmission, the result is always "port closed".

The firewall GUI is called Firewall Configuration, which I assume just modifies my personal firewall on my Fedora.

I'm forwarding on port 51413, transmission default port, to the same on the standard IP I got from my router page online. The router is not my Fedora box, but an external TP link modem.

I tried disabling the firewall, specifically FirewallD on Fedora, but nothing changed.

EDIT: SOLVED
i finally solved: apparently transmission had a problem with the option "use UPnP or NAT-PMP port forwarding from my router" , which automatically fowarded port 51413 on the router. disabling the option and forwarding manually another port worked.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be very clear about which box is which, and what ports and IPs are involved? Is your Fedora 23 Linux box also your router, or is it just the Transmission client box sitting behind some other, as-yet-unspecified router? What ports did you forward and to what IP:Port pairs did you forward them to? What is this "firewall gui app you can download through the software manager" — Is it safe to assume it's something that adjusts the "personal firewall"/"software firewall" running on the Fedora host? Did you try turning off the Fedora box's local firewall all together?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts (this one and http://superuser.com/users/601286/tidus). See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts. That will allow you to edit and comment on your own question.

Comment: "forwarding port 51413" or "forwarding on port 51413"?

Comment: i finally solved: apparently transmission had a problem with the option
"use UPnP or NAT-PMP port forwarding from my router" , which automatically fowarded port 51413 on the router. disabling the option and forwarding manually another port worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work at two levels, *computer* and *modem router*:

1. Open *Transmission* and go in *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Network*
2. Copy the port number (eg. **51414**)
3. Check "Use UPnP or NAT-PMP port forwarding from my router"
   [image]
4. Open a terminal and, as root, give the following command to open the
   port in the firewall **permanently**:

> `$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=51414/tcp`
>
> For a **temporary** solution, instead (after reboot this firewall setting
>   is lost), you can use this other command:
>
> `$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 51414 -j ACCEPT`

5. Now the last step, that is the [manual configuration](https://transmissionbt.com/help/gtk/1.9x/html/pfrouter.html) of your modem
   router, by opening a web browser at your IP address (check the previous guide
   to find out it: it could be 192.168.1.100, or 192.168.1.1, or 192.168.178.1, or something else)
6. For [FRITZ!Box 7490 modem router](https://portforward.com/fritz-box/7490/), for example, you need to go in
   *Internet* -> *Permit Access* => select a *device* => now click on *New
   Sharing* or, if you have olready one, click on the *edit icon* to *add a
   new forwarding* => *New permit access* -> as application choose *other
   application* to enter a custom name -> as protocol choose *TCP* -> then
   as port *51414* in all the three fields => OK => OK => Apply
7. Now test *Transmission*, going in *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Network* ->
   *Check port* => **OPEN**!